# Differences between android studio preview and phone

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have an ImageView called 'neura_bar_img' and two TextViews to its right:

[image]

The XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/summaryCard"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topCard"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:layout_heightPercent="25%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="113dp"
                android:id="@+id/neura_bar_img"
                android:src="@drawable/detailed_daily_sum"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/detailed_goal_text"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/graphicsBlue"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/detailed_bites_eaten_text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sports_part_text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/neura_bar_img"
                android:text="---"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/graphicsOrange"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bites_part_text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/neura_bar_img"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/neura_bar_img"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/graphicsGrey"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

On Android Studio's preview it looks just fine. But on some devices there is a gap between the ImageView and the Text View. Here is an example:

[image]

- This picture was taken from LG G3 for example but I saw the same problem on Moto G

I have no idea why this is happening, and didn't find any similar cases online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of layout did you use to encapsulate your UI elements ? for example `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, ...

Comment: They are all wrapped in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Technically we don't see how your layout has been built, we need to see the full layout (for example you used `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in the imageView)

Comment: I've edited the question and put the whole cardView (the whole layout is realy long. this is just the interesting part).

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imageView` is missing the `scaleType` attribute which is set by default as `fitcenter` making it depending on the device, try this

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ZKt_qF_kgP"
  android:layout_width="270dp"
  android:layout_height="113dp"
  android:src="@drawable/neura_bar_img"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
```

Also different android often has different screen metrics:

LG 3 : `480dp x 835dp`
Moto G : `360dp x 640dp`
Nexus 4 (default android studio preview in my case ) : `384dp x 640dp`
See this [table](https://design.google.com/devices/) for more devices metrics.

if you want to adjust your application for the three device above you need to specify a layout for each metric (here width) in the corresponding folders:

`layout-sw360dp`  `layout-sw480dp` `layout-sw384dp`

Comment: I want to be able to support all devices, but I still can't understand why 0dp margin between these to views creates a gap. because 0dp = 0px. so i doesnt matter what density the phone has.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't thought about this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is probably the type of layout you are using.

screen densities differ, some of the values you are using (px,dp,etc.) might not look the same on different devices.

I almost always use the LinearLayout because of the fact that i can use the "weight" attribute.

I don't know if this is the answer you are looking for, but i tried :D

Comment: Sorry I just notice that the XML code was missing.
 As you can see now, there is 0dp margin_left, so I can't see why It should differ in any phone.